# commutative diagram of groups in Lang's algebra

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, exact-sequence

In Lang's Algebra (section I.3), 
he says that we can describe the third isomorphism theorem
$\frac{G}{K}/\frac{H}{K}\cong G/H$
by the following commutative diagram. 
\begin{array}{c}
0 & \to & H & \to & G & \to & G/H & \to & 0\\
  &     & \downarrow \text{can} & & \downarrow\text{can} & & \downarrow\text{id} & & \\
0 & \to & H/K & \to & G/K & \to & G/H & \to & 0
\end{array}
It inspired me to have an idea.
We know that there are many important theorem which is stated by an isomorphism.
For example, 
$\frac{H}{H\cap K}\cong\frac{HK}{K}$, 
$G/Z(G)\cong \text{inn } G$, ...

**Question 1:** Are there commutative diagrams to describe these two example?
That is, 
\begin{array}{c}
0 & \to & ? & \to & ? & \to & ? & \to & 0\\
  &     & \downarrow \text{?} & & \downarrow\text{?} & & \downarrow\text{?} & & \\
0 & \to & H\cap K & \to & H & \to & HK/K & \to & 0
\end{array}
and
\begin{array}{c}
0 & \to & ? & \to & ? & \to & ? & \to & 0\\
  &     & \downarrow \text{?} & & \downarrow\text{?} & & \downarrow\text{?} & & \\
0 & \to & Z(G) & \to & G & \to & \text{inn }G & \to & 0
\end{array}

**Question 2:** Can we find some rules (or an algorithm) to fill the the following commutative diagram.
Then to produce an isomorphism?
\begin{array}{c}
0 & \to & H & \to & G & \to & G/H & \to & 0\\
  &     & \downarrow \text{?} & & \downarrow\text{?} & & \downarrow\text{?} & & \\
0 & \to & ? & \to & ? & \to & ? & \to & 0
\end{array}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\inn}{inn}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$
Ad Question 1: You could write
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \rightarrow & H\cap K & \rightarrow & H & \rightarrow & HK/K & \rightarrow & 0\\
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & K & \rightarrow & HK & \rightarrow & HK/K & \rightarrow & 0
\end{array}
$$
where all the arrows are evident. The isomorphism $G/Z(G)\cong \inn(G)$ is more tricky. If you really really want to use commutative diagrams to show this, then consider the exact commutative diagram (all the arrows being the evident ones and $G\rightarrow \Aut(G)$ maps an element to conjugation by that element)
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
& & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & \\
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & Z(G) & \rightarrow & Z(G) & \rightarrow & G/Z(G) & & \\
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & Z(G) & \rightarrow & G & \rightarrow & G/Z(G) & \rightarrow & 0\\
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & \inn(G) & \rightarrow & \Aut(G) & \rightarrow & \Aut(G)/\inn(G) & \rightarrow & 0\\
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
 & & \inn(G) & \rightarrow & \Aut(G)/\inn(G) & \rightarrow &\Aut(G)/\inn(G) & \rightarrow & 0\\
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
& & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & \\
\end{array}
$$
Now, by the [Snake Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma), there exists a homomorphism $\delta\colon G/Z(G) \rightarrow \inn(G)$ connecting the end of the 2nd row with the start of the 5th row and such that
$$
0\rightarrow Z(G)\rightarrow Z(G)\xrightarrow{0} G/Z(G) \xrightarrow\delta \inn(G) \xrightarrow{0} \Aut(G)/\inn(G) \rightarrow \Aut(G)/\inn(G) \rightarrow 0
$$
is exact. In particular, $\delta$ is an isomorphism.

To shortly address your second question: It might help to study the [short Five Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_five_lemma) or, more generally the [Five Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma).

Comment: @@. Thanks. I want to use the commutative diagram to help my student to remember these isomorphism. But it seems unrealistic.